# Trade me API to retrieve the sold items

Tags: java, api

I'm using TradeMe API to retrieve the sold items. I've got Access token and secrete access token.

Base string is:

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.tmsandbox.co.nz%2Fv1%2FMyTradeMe%2FSoldItems%2FLast3Days.xml&oauth_consumer_key%3D6085D4BB6470D6D19A87C95250B0DE67B3%26oauth_nonce%3Dfc2v9dfhvodue63158nfgv8rmi%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1386664558%26oauth_token%3DCB062F16423A86ABD70BCDAE526DB242A5%26oauth_version%3D1.0

Signature is:

> O13VZ4S2g9IYUdUe2bvSi2MEedM=

Signature is calculated as

`StringUtils.getBytesUsAscii(consumer_secret_key+"&"+secretAccessToken))`

as they suggested

URL :
https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/MyTradeMe/SoldItems/Last24Hours.xml?deleted=false&page=1&photo_size=Thumbnail&rows=50

Authorization header:

> OAuth, oauth_consumer_key="6085D4BB6470D6D19A87C95250B0DE67B3",
>   oauth_nonce="akl05eckls51nk5taohls0cnd4",
>   oauth_signature="O13VZ4S2g9IYUdUe2bvSi2MEedM%3D"oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>   oauth_timestamp="1386664558",
>   oauth_token="CB062F16423A86ABD70BCDAE526DB242A5", oauth_version="1.0",

It is giving me an error.

> Error java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for
>   URL:
>   https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/MyTradeMe/SoldItems/Last24Hours.xml?deleted=false&page=1&photo_size=Thumbnail&rows=50

Can any one tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432263/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-500)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response code: 500 usually arises for any uncaught exception the underlying web server application is not able to deal with. Or even for a caught exception that comes from an unhandled / unexpected data-flow.

You should be able to look at the server logs and figure out where and why that error happens.

According to your description and the complexity of that task it is unlikely possible to guess what is going on there...

Comment: Hi everyone. . sorry that was my mistake.. The authorization header was wrong. There should not be comma after header and also I was missing comma and space before 'oauth_signature_method'