# Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL for GET request

Tags: java, rest, hp-quality-center

I'm trying to query ALM defects with a filter condition, but I get the below exception. The same URL is working fine when accessed through a browser.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
http://ealm11.mycomp.com:80/qcbin/rest/domains/TESTING/projects/2014/defects?query={owner['das'  or 'john' or 'kim'];status[Assigned]}&fields=id    at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1485)
    at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
```

Also, if the URL does not have the "or" condition in one of the param values as below

```
http://ealm11.mycomp.com:80/qcbin/rest/domains/TESTING/projects/2014/defects?query={owner['das'];status[Assigned]}&fields=id
```

it's working but when i introduce "or" conditions, java is throwing the above error.

Comment: What is the response if you put the query from java in your browser? Now you are comparing red apples with green apples :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432263/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-500

Comment: @Salandur The URL which is causing exception in Java works fine in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with a "%20" for spaces in the URL?

```
http://ealm11.mycomp.com:80/qcbin/rest/domains/TESTING/projects/2014/defects?query={owner['das'%20or%20'john'%20or%20'kim'];status[Assigned]}&fields=id
```

Comment: Tried but no success.

Comment: Is it possible to post the full URL. It *may* be something else in the URL.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, you're right having spaces replaced with %20 and removing " ' " in above url worked.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that "'" was an invalid URL character as well.

Answer (score 0):

Errorcodes from `500` and upwards are errors at serverside.

This means you can't do anything against it.

But in fact I think, it should be a `406 Bad Request` and you did a malformed request and the server has an error which throws an exception.

Are you sure, that `OR` is valid for this request?

**Update**
You may need to [urlencode your query](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (only true for the query part). Browser are encoding automatic, java not.

Comment: yes it is, otherwise i would've got an error when accessed through browser.